# Django Static Files in Production Using Whitenoise

Tags: django, production

Firstly apologies for the length of this.

I have a django project running on Centos6 and Apache using a C-Panel plugin to install Django and I am trying to serve the static files in production.
My project uses Django 1.9 and I am trying to use Whitenoise to serve my static files.

My settings.py contains the following:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE ='whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'common-static'),
```

And this is my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
)
```

This is the wsgi.py for my django app

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And this is the one generated by the plugin:

```
import os
import sys
import site
vepath = '/home/mysite/virtualenv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
site.addsitedir(vepath)

sys.path.append('/home/mysite/djangosites/mysite')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","mysite.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have DEBUG = False in my settings.py.
When I run ./manage.py collectstatic the files are collected and if I run the server with 0.0.0.0:8000 the static files are found.

I tried add the following to both wsgi.py files but to no avail:

```
from whitenoise.django importDjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Any advice on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add that my IP is not publicly available at the moment only via my laptop hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late response but it might help other people searching for an answer.

You do NOT have to include 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware' when you're using 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'.

Also, you don't need to make any changes in wsgi.py. Adding the middleware will take care of everything for you.